# How to add shapes to an empty webpage using Atom text editor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, atom-editor, khan-academy

I am new to programming but have completed most of the practice on the drawing and animation section on Khan Academy. Simply based on what I understand, I can place javascript code within a script tag placed between a body tag. However, when I opened my webpage, all I got was the style and the headings.

How can I animate or add shapes using the Atom text editor? I tried looking at Khan Academy and noticed that they also use processing.js, is that a reason my code won't run on my webpage? The code I will provide below will be my attempt to draw a sun growing larger and larger. The code inside the script tag is the exact and only code I needed to make the program run perfectly. I am not fully understanding if I am missing something. If not, can you help show the code for drawing a simple circle or rectangle(PS khan academy simply uses the rect and ellipse functions)?

Please note that I searched the stack for this and was unable to find a satisfying solution. Also, I used type=javascript in the script tags but the end result was the same when I clicked my webpage.

Thanks

MY code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello User</title>
    <h1 class="text_color">I am blue text on a screen</h1>
  </head>
  <style>
    body{
      background-color:rgb(5,113,176);
      font-family:arial;
      font-size:20px;
    }
      .text_color{
        color:blue;
        font-family:arial;
      }
  </style>
  <body>
    <script>
              noStroke();
        // the beautiful blue sky
        background(82, 222, 240);

        // the starting size for the sun
        var sunSize = 30;

        //Animation part

        draw = function() {

             // The sun, a little circle on the horizon
            fill(255, 204, 0);
            ellipse(200, 298, sunSize, sunSize);

            // The land, blocking half of the sun
            fill(76, 168, 67);
            rect(0, 300, 400, 100);
            sunSize = sunSize+1;
};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The functions backbround, ellipse etc are not defined as part of js. Probably defined in Processing.js therfore you need a script tag above your other script tag with a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to link p5.js into your HTML Document, because you use function's that are declared in p5.js.

Try:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@0.10.2/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

At the bottom of `<body>`

then put your noStroke(); and Background(); into the funtion setup() because p5 variable and function names are not available outside setup(), draw(), mousePressed(), etc.

```
function setup(){
    noStroke();
    background(82, 222, 240);
  }
```

Hope this will work for you.